# Can Firebase generate static files?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-storage

As the title says, can I use firebase to generate static files?

EG: Could I have some kind of markdown stored in the DB, and have a static html file generated every time it is updated?

Or is it only a deployment task to update the static files?

Comment: There is currently no way to run your code on Firebase's servers. Where would the code to generate the HTML run? And where would it write the generated files to?

Comment: You can't, but I would just use a server for something like that in combination with firebase being your database. I used firebase in combination with a node server hosted on heroku to do something similar.

Comment: OK thanks guys.   I guess if it were a react app pulling data from firebase, then the resulting render could of been cached... kind of like a universal react app might first render on the server side..... except I guess the static file hosting is just static.